# When is [Time to be received] property of msmq message evaluated?

Tags: msmq

When I send a message and set the TTBR property on the message:
    QueuedMessage.TimeToBeReceived = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

When is this property evaluated and the message deleted or deadlettered?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation doesn't specify when or how the property is evaluated, that's probably deliberate.  By doing that Microsoft keep their options open.  They are free to change when and how the property is evaluated any time they want to.

There are some hints.  For instance the [PROPID_M_TIME_TO_BE_RECEIVED](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711348.aspx) description says:

> In each hop, Message Queuing subtracts the time elapsed on the applicable computer from the value of PROPID_M_TIME_TO_BE_RECEIVED when it dispatches the message to the next computer, where a new timer is set.

But we probably shouldn't read too much into that.  The phrase "... where a new timer is set." might be shorthand for some other non-timer related code and not an indication that an actual timer is created.